How to run GraphQL within Docker
Currently I'm working on a backend with GraphQL and Hot Chocolate.
The backend gets data from openweathermap.org.
If I'm running dotnet run locally everything is fine. I can see the interface of Banana Cake (http://localhost:5000/graphql).
Now I want to use a docker for this. So I've created a Dockerfile and build my container and run it. It is also working. But I can't connect to the graphql interface.
Startup.cs file
using HotChocolate.AspNetCore.Playground;

namespace WeatherBackend
{
        public class Startup
        {
                private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;

        public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            _env = env;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddHttpClient<WeatherService>();
            services.AddGraphQLServer()
                .AddQueryType<WeatherQueryType>()
                .AddApolloTracing()
                .AddType<WeatherType>()
                .ModifyRequestOptions(opt => opt.IncludeExceptionDetails = _env.IsDevelopment());
            
            services.AddOptions();
            services.Configure<OpenWeatherMapOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ApiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("OpenWeatherMapApiKey");;
            });
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseCors(builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyHeader()
                       .AllowAnyMethod();
            });
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapGraphQL("/graphql");
            });
        }
    }
}

Dockerfile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG configuration=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WeatherBackend.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "WeatherBackend.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "WeatherBackend.csproj" -c $configuration -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG configuration=Release
RUN dotnet publish "WeatherBackend.csproj" -c $configuration -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WeatherBackend.dll"]

Running docker build -t weather-backend-image . and than docker run -p 8080:5000 weather-backend-image:latest and than connecting to http://localhost:5000/graphql no Banana Cake Interface is seen.
Also the logs shows no errors
docker logs 0c750cfe551d
dbug: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host[1]
      Hosting starting
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://[::]:8080
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /app
dbug: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host[2]
      Hosting started

Can someone please help to dockerize my backend, please.

Any errors in the container logs?

docker logs <container_id> shows me that everything is working fine
dbug: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host[1]       Hosting starting info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]       Now listening on: http://[::]:8080 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]       Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down. info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]       Hosting environment: Production info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]       Content root path: /app dbug: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host[2]       Hosting started

Post the logs in the question itself. There's nothing special to GraphQL anyway. You need to create a docker container that forwards the correct external ports to the ports ASP.NET Core listens. In .NET 7 and later though you can publish directly to an image, without having to create a Dockerfile. That reduces the number of things that can go wrong

no Banana Cake Interface is seen. what do you get? If the port wasn't forwarded you'd get a browser error. If not, either the UI isn't registered or it's on a different URL

It is not reachable so I get a browser error.

In the HotChocolate Intro just app.MapGraphQL();  maps to /graphql. .NET 8 doesn't require a Startup class either. You should probably start from scratch with ASP.NET Core's templates (ie no Startup) and follow the Intro. Add one thing at a time and make sure it's working before adding another

Also notice Now listening on: http://[::]:8080. You forwarded to 5000 instead. -p 8080:5000 means that the external port 8080 is forwarded to the internal 5000. Nothing listens to that though

Okay that was the main issue. I totally mixed up the ports! Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos
